# Lithium PHP framework - can not validate empty number correctly ...

Tags: validation, frameworks, numbers, zero, lithium

I have this model in a project, built with Lithium PHP framework:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

class Prices extends Base {

  protected $_schema = array(
    '_id'          => 'id',
    .......
    'price'        => array('float', 'default' => 0)
  );

  public $validate = array(
    .......
    'price' => array(
      array('notEmpty', 'message' => 'Price cannot be empty.'),
      array('numeric', 'message' => 'Price must be number.')
    )
  );

}

?>
```

The problem is that the model treats zero as invalid price too.

I tried with adding additional properties - `allowEmptyValue` - with no result.

I tried with custom validation rule - it gets ignored. (???)

I tried to remove the `float` from the `$_schema` and then it accepts zeros ... but then it also accepts text for price. (?!?!?!)

Do you have any idea what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the custom validation. For example:

```
Validator::add('price', function($value, $rule, $option){
    if(floatval($value) == 0){
        return false;
    }
    //you can add more rules here

    return true;
});
```

and add "price" to the list of rules

```
'price' => array(
      array('notEmpty', 'message' => 'Price cannot be empty.'),
      array('numeric', 'message' => 'Price must be number.'),
      array('price', 'message' => 'Please enter a valid price.')
    )
```

Comment: Yes, correct ... but then I have another problem: in the custom validation rule the value is typecast to float ... I guess because of the line in the `$_schema` => `'price'        => array('float', 'default' => 0)`. And then - if I enter text for price and submit - the value in the custom validation is `float(0)`. Can I workaround this?

Comment: (If I remove the `float` word in the `$_schema` property - then in the custom validation - if the value is text - then it gets typecast to `int(0)`.)

Comment: what if you remove both `float` and `default`?